# Actionlink doesn't use all the row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using bootstrap to fit my elements on the right place, when I try to use it with the actionlink from asp.net it doesn't use all the rows, it just uses the size of the text, I want the element to use all the rows so I can center the text how can I do that? I don't want to use margins or other stuff to do something like that

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:5px;border:2px solid black;border-radius:8px">
        <h5 style="text-align:center">Os mais Recentes</h5>
        @foreach (var i in recentes)
        {
            <div class="col-md-12">@Html.ActionLink(i.TipoTrabalho, "Edit", new { id = i.DesafioId }, new { @style = "text-align:center" })</div>
            <hr />
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anchor use the size of the text because is an inline element. Use in css a { display: block}

Comment: cant choose your answer as the correct here, but you are awesome thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

As Germano Plebani stated in the comments, you can use CSS display to change from an inline element to a block element. `{display: block}`